# centering a background image, seems so much harder than it should be

Tags: html, css, background, centering, background-position

okay its been about an hour of googling and at this point im probably overthinking it.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="#wrapper">
         <div class="container-fluid">
        <img src="background-image.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img {
background-position: center center;
}
```

all the above code does is places the img in the upper left corner.

ive also tried, fixed, static, relative, absolute on the img tag and it changes nothing.

am i targeting the wrong spot by using img in the css?

Answer (score 3):

Right now you're positioning background image in CSS, which should be defined also in CSS, but you're using a IMG tag.

```
<style>
div.container-fluid: { 
  background-image: url('background-image.jpeg');   
  background-position: center;
}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
Your text here
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, why not define the image as a background in CSS instead of using the img tag? Also you have some syntax nesting errors, be careful to close tags appropriately.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.container-fluid {
   background:url('background-image.jpeg') center;
   min-height:500px /* adding height to see the div, otherwise it won't show up */
}
```

Make sure the image path is correct in relation to the CSS file

Comment: thank you so much, its still not working but i think this is the best way to handle it!    my background img is literally in my project folder with no path(yet) do i need to specify  /projfolder/background-image.jpeg?

Comment: You won't see it because the `container-fluid` div has no set height - try adding `height:500px` to test it... Is the background image in the same folder as the CSS file?

Comment: woah that worked, I would have sat here forever before thinking to add some height to the div, thank you for saving me a giant headache today :)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it with an element that uses `text-align: center;`. Example:

## HTML

```
<div class="center-me">
    <img src="background-image.jpeg" alt="" />
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.center-me {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Or you could add `text-align: center;` to `container-fluid`, but that will probably affect other things in that container:

```
.container-fluid {
    text-align: center;
}
```